# pyqtgraph scrolling plots: plot in chunks, show only latest 10s samples in current window

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have trouble using pygtgraph scrolling plots

### Expected Results

The expected results are quite similar to the [pyqtgraph-examples-scrolling plots-plot5](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/examples/scrollingPlots.py)

X-values are times, which can be generated by a simple function. Y-Values are random values.

Each 10 seconds samples as one chunk and each plot can have max. 30 seconds samples, which means 3 chunks. **The current plot window only shows the latest 10 seconds samples**

For example, now there are total 60 seconds samples:

- Data between 50s-60s will be viewed in the current window
- Data between 30s-50s could be viewed by **using the mouse to drag the x-axis backward**
- Data between 0-30s will not be displayed

### My Code

My current code is below, it can only show latest 30s data.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
import random


win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
win.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plots')

p1 = win.addPlot()
p1.setYRange(0,10)

xVal = [0]
yVal = [0]

def genTime():  # used to generate time
    t = 0
    while True:
        t += np.random.random_sample()
        yield t
        t = np.ceil(t)

xTime = genTime() 

#=====================================================

viewSize = 10   # current window show only latest 10s data
plotSize = 30   # plot 30s data -> 3 chunk
lstCurves = []  # List for Curves

def update():
    global p1, xVal, yVal, lstCurves

    #for c in lstCurves:
    #    c.setPos(xVal[-1], 0)

    i = np.ceil(xVal[-1]) % viewSize  # e.g. when time is 9.2s -> one 10s view size is full, append to curves list as one chunk
    if i == 0:
        curve = p1.plot()
        lstCurves.append(curve)
        xValLast = xVal[-1]
        yValLast = yVal[-1]

        xVal = [xValLast]
        yVal = [yValLast]

        while len(lstCurves) > 3:  # max 3 chunk (30 s)
            p1.removeItem(lstCurves.pop(0))  # remove the oldest 10s
        
    else:
        curve = lstCurves[-1]    # latest 10s curve
        
    xVal.append(next(xTime))
    yVal.append(random.randint(0,9))
    curve.setData(xVal, yVal)
    print(len(lstCurves))

    
#======================================================

timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(1000)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

### Problem

I have tried using `curve.setPos(xx, 0)`, It looks like the whole curve is moving along the x-axis, but the **mapping relationship between X-value and Y-value is broken**

I have also tried using `setXRange()` to dynamically change x-axis display-range in `update()` func. But in this case, I can't use the mouse to drag the x-axis back to view the old data any more.

My English is not good, I hope you can understand my question. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to select the view with the drag of the mouse? or it can be, for example, a slider?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The reasons your code don't do what you want are:

- When you drag to view the other chunks, you disable the automatic auto-range of the plot, after that, you will have to manually drag the plot every time you want to see the new data. Also, by default, the auto-range of the plot will cover all the data that you are plotting.
- When you use the `setRange()` method inside the `update` function, it will force that range every time you add another value to the data. Then the drag will not work as you want

### What can you do

Well, from my perspective using the mouse drag to visualize the other data is not very convenient, I suggest to use an external widget to control the range of the data you want to view, like, a slider, scroll bar, spin box, ...
A `QScrollBar` can do the job and it will look esthetic in a GUI.

Before my *Alternative Solution*, I have a suggestion for you:

- Use objects to create your widget, generate a class and use the variables as attributes, with this you avoid the use of the keyword `global`, and you could reuse the widget for other purposes.

### Alternative Solution

Try this:

```
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        ## Creating the Widgets and Layouts
        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.sbutton = QtGui.QPushButton("Start / Continue")
        self.ebutton = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollBar(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        ## Creating the variables and constants
        self.data = [[0], [random.randint(0,9)]]  ## [xVal, yVal] to create less variables
        self.plot_item = self.plot_widget.plot(*self.data)
        self.plot_widget.setYRange(0, 10)
        self.xTime = self.genTime()
        self.vsize = 10
        self.psize = 30
        ## Building the Widget
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.sbutton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ebutton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        ## Changing some properties of the widgets
        self.plot_widget.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        self.ebutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.scroll.setEnabled(False)
        self.scroll.setMaximum(self.psize-self.vsize)
        self.scroll.setValue(self.psize-self.vsize)
        ## Coneccting the signals
        self.sbutton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ebutton.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.scroll.valueChanged.connect(self.upd_scroll)

    def genTime(self):  # used to generate time
        t = 0
        while True:
            t += np.random.random_sample()
            yield t
            t = np.ceil(t)

    def upd_scroll(self):
        val = self.scroll.value()
        xmax = np.ceil(self.data[0][-1+self.vsize-self.psize+val])-1
        xmin = xmax-self.vsize
        self.plot_widget.setXRange(xmin, xmax)

    def update(self):
        num = len(self.data[0])
        if num <= self.psize:
            self.plot_item.setData(*self.data)
        else:
            self.plot_item.setData(
                self.data[0][-self.psize:],
                self.data[1][-self.psize:]
            )

        if num == self.vsize:
            self.scroll.setEnabled(True)
        self.data[0].append(next(self.xTime))
        self.data[1].append(random.randint(0,9))
        if num > self.vsize :
            self.upd_scroll()
     
    def start(self):
        self.sbutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.ebutton.setEnabled(True)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def stop(self):
        self.sbutton.setEnabled(True)
        self.ebutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.timer.stop()
        self.upd_scroll()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.stop()
        event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It may look like this:

[image]