# Is threre a way to autopan to the last value at the end of a graph in pyqtgpraph?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I'm working on a Python UI project that I'm drawing live data to the pyqtgraph widgets (I'm doing real time data drawing to the graphs with 1hz freq). This is my first project with Python and pyqtgraph so I'm still trying to learn, everything works fine for a prototype so far.

My problem is when I start drawing, after a while data starts to add up as the plotted line extends to the right and the view auto-pans to follow the data, eventually it falls behind and end of the plotted data line extends off screen. It continues to pan to the right at a consistent rate, but is no longer showing the most recent data. I know that the autopan function centers the the view for current average. For example if I'm at the 200th data point at the time, I'm seing 100th value at the center of a graph and 150 at the end of a graph, but what I need is I want to see 200th value at the end of the graph.

I'm getting my values from a CSV file turned into a data frame by using pandas and PYQT Designer iu file for widgets Code for drawing looks like this:

```
//////////////////////some other code later//////////////////////////


self.f = pd.read_csv('test_serial.csv')
    self.fd = DataFrame(self.f, columns=['PACKET_TYPE ','TEMP'])

    # Creating Telemetry variables for graphs
    # TODO Create variable for every telemetry value
    self.TEMP = self.fd.TEMP
    self.PACKET_TYPE = self.fd.PACKET_TYPE

    self.textBrowser.append(self.fd.to_string())

    if (self.PACKET_TYPE == 'C').any(): 
        self.c_graph.setLimits(maxXRange=10, maxYRange=100)
        self.c_graph.setLabel(axis='left', text='c_temp_value')
        self.c_graph.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.c_graph.setBackground('w')

        self.c_graph.plot(self.TEMP, symbol='t1', pen='b', symbolPen='g', symbolBrush=0.2, clear=True)
```

I also find this it has a custom auto pan tool but didn't understand it well and can't manage to implement it into my project: https://gitlab.com/taurus-org/taurus_pyqtgraph/-/tree/main/taurus_pyqtgraph

I figured a temporary solution while looking at this https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/viewbox.html

I added these lines:

```
self.total_rows = self.fd[self.fd.columns[0]].count()
self.c_Pressure.setLimits(xMin=self.total_rows-50 ,xMax=self.total_rows)
```

But now the problem is I cannot go back and see past values, because the view is fixed, only problem remains is this now.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Read this, and try it , maybe it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/65332619/13929529

Comment: Thank you, i will look it. The temporary solution i did was good for now.