# Is there a PyQtGraph parameter for autorange which limits how many points are visible?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have a PyQtGraph (Line graph) which constantly has new values added too it, and I am using the plot.autoRange() function to update the viewBox, but the problem is that I am using custom Ticks (Time, 12:00PM for example), and if it has more than 10-ish values the x-ticks overlap when it auto ranges. Is it possible to for example make autoRange only show the last 10 values?

Currently I found a workaround by removing the first value once 10 has been reached, but this really isn't optimal since the old data isn't in the graph anymore.

Comment: Check this, maybe it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65510576/13929529

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if you want that kind of custom behavior, you need to use the `setRange` method:

https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setRange

If you want to stick with autoRange, the autoRange method takes an optional `items` argument; what you can do is create an overlapping curve of *just* the last 10 points (that you want to display) and call the `autoRange` function on just that curve, not all the items in the ViewBox.  If they overlap entirely it should be visually not noticeable (but if you have mouse related events, you may have more complication).

Hopefully that helps